# Bulk delete not working as expected in Node app

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I can't seem to get the bulk delete message working. When I give it a go in Discord I get the "An error has occurred" And anything I do doesn't seem to work. Perhaps it's something obvious I'm doing wrong.

```
client.on('message', message => {

    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(' ');

    switch (args[0]) {
        case 'clear':
            if(!message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES')) return message.reply('You dont have the permisions to clear')
            if(args[1] > 99) return message.reply('Too many messages, You can only delete 99<')
            if(!args[1]) return message.reply ('Please specify how many messages you want clearing...')
            message.channel.bulkDelete(args[1]+1).then(() => {
                message.channel.send(`:white_check_mark: Sucessfully cleared ${args[1]} messages...`)
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err)
                return message.channel.send('An error occured...');
            })
        }
    })
```

Comment: What do you get in `err`?

Comment: I get The 'get' problem if this is any help.

Comment: What's the full error?

Comment: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
limit: int value should be less than or equal to 100.
    at RequestHandler.execute (/Users/harrison/Desktop/GTA V Assistant/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:170:25)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
  method: 'get',
  path: '/channels/744355429298995290/messages?limit=901',
  code: 50035,
  httpStatus: 400
}

Comment: Yes I have just tried it, That was it, it was adding the one just on the end, So if you wanted to delete '90' it would make it '901', ive fixed it now thankyou

Comment: Accidentally deleted my comment lol. Good to hear. For anyone wondering, `args[1]` needed to be converted to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

The message.channel.bulkDelete(args[1]+1).then(() => { was the problem , the '+1' was literally adding 1 on to the end so if you wanted to delete '90' messages it would make it '901' and as the max is 100 this doesn't work.

client.on('message', message => {

```
let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(' ');

switch (args[0]) {
    case 'clear':
        if(!message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES')) return message.reply('You dont have the permisions to clear')
        if(args[1] > 99) return message.reply('Too many messages, You can only delete 99<')
        if(!args[1]) return message.reply ('Please specify how many messages you want clearing...')
        message.channel.bulkDelete(args[1]).then(() => {
            message.channel.send(`:white_check_mark: Sucessfully cleared ${args[1]} messages...`)
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
            return message.channel.send('An error occured...');
        })
    }
})
```